# Where do I start if I want to a create a syllable like /ba/ or /pa/?

Tags: phonetics, speech-synthesis

I want to create some syllable like /ba/, /pa/, /ta/, /da/, with either Praat or Klatt synthesis interface. But I was overwhelmed by the information I found on the Internet. I was wondering what I should know if I just want to make these syllables.

Comment: Does this solve the problem? http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Source-filter_synthesis_3__The_ba-da_continuum.html.

Comment: Thanks! It helps. I'm looking at the Speech Synthesis part of the Praat help.

Comment: I followed the instructions but still can't get a /ba/-/da/ continuum, but a bunch of buzzing sounds. I'm trying other tutorials.

Comment: The sound will be buzzy; but change "Filter (no scale)" to plain "Filter", and that will eliminate the massive peak clipping in the "bada" files. It still doesn't sound like "ba", but now you can start playing around with formant values.