# Text-to-speech for arbitrary vowels (i.e not just ipa)

Tags: vowels, speech-synthesis

So my understanding is vowel sounds can be modelled in a
[2-d space together with roundedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_vowel_chart_with_audio) in terms of location and openness or equivalently in terms of first and second *formants*.

You get pictures like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_phonology#/media/File:Korean_short_vowel_chart.svg).

**I want a tool that can synthesis all these vowel sounds**. Ideally I would have something where I could drag my finger around a 2-d space and have it change the vowels sounds.

My use case is partly just for fun, and partly to help me learn to make different vowel sounds: being able to explore *around* the sound that you  want to make is pretty useful in terms of honing in on the target sound.

Comment: My best not-really-an-answer is: it's definitely possible to create something like this, but I don't think anyone has yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A colleague had such a device some years ago, but it depended on a touch interface that was a decade before there were touch interfaces. Theoretically it would not be hard to create such an interface, where a touch corresponds to F1/F2 values; then you simply synthesize the vowel with those formant values. Praat allows you to play around like that: see [this question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/25530) with comments on how to create a synthesis script (it would be easier in the case of just a vowel rather than a CV transition). There is an online Klatt synthesis interface [here](http://www.asel.udel.edu/speech/tutorials/synthesis/vowels.html), where you can specify all of the formants and anything else of interest. The hard part is mapping from intuitive vowel positions to actual formant values (which is not *terribly* hard).

For educational and entertainment purposes, I highly recommend using the online Klatt program and play with formant values, not being bound by empirically-justified limits on particular formants: see what happens when F1 is 1800, and thereby find the boundaries between vowel-like sounds and machine-buzzing noises. This gave me an appreciation for the importance of F1.

As noted by Jeremy Needle, [Pink Trombone](http://dood.al/pinktrombone) kind of approaches the desideratum of an articulation-based synthesizer (it looks "backwards", i.e. the vocal tract looks rightwards). With a mouse you can only change one articulatory setting at a time, but with a touch screen, you can get multiple constrictions. You could use Audacity sound capture to extract samples and find formants.

Comment: I agree: the vowel space continuous, so you just use any values. I wanted to mention that the Pink Trombone (https://dood.al/pinktrombone/) lets you do this ‘hands on’, but I don’t think you can extract any numbers (or audio) at all.

Comment: Pink Trombone is pretty nice. Playing with it it looks like the interface for adjusting the tongue is pretty close to the 'front-back and close-open space' used for IPA.